# Вывести службы Windows в listbox. C#

Tags: c#, службы

Как вывести службы Windows отдельный список?

Пытался сделать так:

```
ServiceController[] scServices;
scServices = ServiceController.GetServices();
listbox1.Items.AddRange(scServices)
```

Но ничего не получилось.

Comment: Используйте scServices[i].ServiceName

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так попробуйте

```
listbox1.Items.AddRange(scServices.Select(s=>s.ServiceName));
```

Либо так в цикле посмотрите

```
foreach(var service in scServices) {
  listbox1.Items.Add(service.ServiceName);
}
```

Comment: К сожалению не работает. Ошибка: Не удаётся преобразовать из "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>" в "System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection"

Comment: @mounten1 `scServices.Select(s=>s.ServiceName).ToList()` тоже не работает?

Comment: Так же не работает. Про эту ошибку писал выше.

Comment: потому что AddRange от тебя ждет объект, а ты суешь ему строку. добавляй по одному как было ниже предложено.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [привязку данных](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8):

```
listbox1.DisplayMember = "ServiceName";
listbox1.DataSource = scServices;
```

Первую строку можно заменить на:

```
listbox1.DisplayMember = nameof(ServiceController.ServiceName);
```